# Correct way to save form_list form instances to the database?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am using a SessionWizardView to divide a small survey over multiple pages.

My problem is that the data from each page of the survey is saved onto a different row in my database, where there are multiple input fields on the one page that information is getting saved on the same row. This is making my DB very cumbersome.

[image]

I isolated the issue to my `save()` function which is getting executed each time there is a `form` in my `form_list`, thus adding new lines in the DB each time.

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    for form in form_list:
        form.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_Prolific_Academic.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

I have tried to execute save directly on the form_list via `form_list.save()` but I get the error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'save'

I have also tried both `join()` and `chain()` to see if I could join together all of the `form` instances to see if I could save them at the same time but was unsuccessful.

I would like to simplify my current solution so that each participants data is saved on a single line in the DB, can anyone tell me how I might go about doing it? Thanks

**Edit**

Example of some of my models.py and forms.py

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ....
    ....

    sender = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='What is your email address?')     

    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) #overwritten in forms.py so passed no more arguments

    SEX = (
        ('1', 'Male'),
        ('2', 'Female'))    
    sex = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, choices=SEX, verbose_name='What sex are you?')

    MARITAL_STATUS = (
        ('SINGLE', "Single"),
        ('INARELATIONSHIP', "In a relationship"),
        ('MARRIED', "Married"),
        ('DIVORCED', "Divorced"),
        ('SEPARATED', "Separated"),
        ('WIDOWED', "Widowed"),)    
    marital_status = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, choices=MARITAL_STATUS, verbose_name='What is your marital status?')             

    INTERNET_USAGE = (
        ('INTERNET_LESS_THAN_ONE_HOUR_A_DAY', 'Less than one hour a day'),
        ('INTERNET_ONE_TO_TWO_HOURS_A_DAY', '1 - 2 hours a day'),
        ('INTERNET_TWO_TO_FOUR_HOURS_A_DAY', '2 - 4 hours a day'),
        ('INTERNET_FOUR_TO_SIX_HOURS_A_DAY', '4 - 6 hours a Day'),
        ('INTERNET_SIX_TO_EIGHT_HOURS_A_DAY', '6 - 8 hours a day'),
        ('INTERNET_EIGHT_PLUS_HOURS_A_DAY', '8 + hours a day'), )
    internet_usage = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, default=None, choices=INTERNET_USAGE)

    SMART_PHONE_OWNERSHIP = (
        ('YES_SMARTPHONE', 'Yes'),
        ('NO_SMARTPHONE', 'No'),)    
    smart_phone_ownership = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True, choices=SMART_PHONE_OWNERSHIP, verbose_name='Do you own a Smartphone?')
```

forms.py

```
class SurveyFormIT1(forms.ModelForm):      
    class Meta:
        model = Person    
        fields = ['instruction_task_one_value', 'instruction_task_one_image']
        widgets = {'instruction_task_one_value' : forms.HiddenInput,
                   'instruction_task_one_image' : forms.HiddenInput}       

class SurveyFormIT2(forms.ModelForm):      
    class Meta:
        model = Person    
        fields = ['instruction_task_two_value', 'instruction_task_two_image']
        widgets = {'instruction_task_two_value' : forms.HiddenInput,
                   'instruction_task_two_image' : forms.HiddenInput}      

class Start(forms.ModelForm):      
    class Meta:
        model = Person    
        fields = ['start']
        widgets = {'start' : forms.HiddenInput}

class SurveyFormA(forms.ModelForm):

    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1920, 1998)), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['prolific_academic_ID', 'sender', 'birthdate', 'sex', 'marital_status', 'state']

class SurveyFormB(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['internet_usage', 'smart_phone_ownership', 'smart_phone_usage']        
        widgets = {'internet_usage' : RadioSelectNotNull,
                   'smart_phone_ownership' : RadioSelectNotNull,
                   'smart_phone_usage' : RadioSelectNotNull,}
```

Comment: Could you show your `form` code and the code that call `done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this solution:**

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    data = {k: v for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items()}
    instance = Person.objects.create(**data)
    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_Prolific_Academic.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

Comment: A little explanation of the problem and your solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Super simple, super janky way, since I don't know your data model:

```
# Accumulate all the filled-in data:
data = {}
for form in form_list:
    for k,v in form.__dict__.items():
        data[k] = v if v else data.get(k)

# Save it to the first form
form_list[0].__dict__.update(data)
form_list[0].save()
```

Comment: Hi, I added an example of my models.py. Your solution only saves the information submitted by the user on the last page. The data from the earlier pages must be getting overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

So the best way to do this is to create an instance of my Person model (which all of my form data was being saved in) and run save on that

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    instance = Person()

    for form in form_list:
        for key, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
            setattr(instance, key, value)
        instance.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_Prolific_Academic.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WizardView` has a `get_form_instance()` method that returns the instance to pass to a particular form. Your problem stems from each form receiving an empty instance which causes all of the forms to create a new separate one when saved.

The method looks like this:

```
def get_form_instance(self, step):
    """
    Returns an object which will be passed to the form for `step`
    as `instance`. If no instance object was provided while initializing
    the form wizard, None will be returned.
    """
    return self.instance_dict.get(step, None)
```

While you can pass `instance_dict` to the wizard's `__init__`, in your case it could be cleaner to subclass the view and set it in `__init__()` right after calling `super()`.

This is cleaner than @Deepend's solution as reuses the inner instance passing machinery as intended rather than injecting instances into forms at a later time.